# Why a LWLock contention be high on Postgres on a temporary basis?

Tags: database, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

Using AWS Aurora (Postgres engine), on occasion i saw spikes in LWLock Wait Events, in particular `LWLock:BufferContent`?

Comment: This is a tech support question for AWS see here [Support](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/?nc2=h_m_ma).

Comment: Lots of different things.  What queries are being slow (or at least running) at the time, and how many of them are there?  What version are you on?  What machine type are you on?

Comment: `Lwlock:Wait`? What are you exactly seeing?